# Android - Programmatically Screenshot and Share to Facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent, android-emulator

I have `button` which function is to take screenshot and share it to Facebook. when i try it in my `Samsung with JellyBean OS` device its working perfectly, but when i try it to `BlueStack with JellyBean OS` and `CheeryMobile with Lollipop OS` things are not working, i check the `Logcat` and i see some error.

my code

`onClick of Button call takeScreenshot();`

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);
        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";
            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            File imageFile = new File(mPath);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            sharePhotoToFacebook(imageFile);
        } catch (Throwable 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


private void sharePhotoToFacebook(File imageFile){
        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        try {
            image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
        //this loginManager helps you eliminate adding a LoginButton to your UI
        loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
        loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);
        loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                try{
                    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                            .setBitmap(image)
                            .setCaption(scoreFinal)
                            .build();
                    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                            .addPhoto(photo)
                            .build();
                    ShareApi.share(content, null);

                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActivityShare.this);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.sucess_shared);
                    dialog.show();
                    Button btnOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
                    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Error on share", String.valueOf(e));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.w("OnCancel", "Canceled by user");
               // System.out.println("onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActivityShare.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.sucess_shared);

                TextView title = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.titleSuccess);
                TextView desc = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.descriptionHere);

                title.setText("Unsuccessfull");
                desc.setText("Something's wrong, Please check your internet connection and try again.");
                dialog.show();

                Button btnOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
                btnOk.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("OnError", String.valueOf(exception));
               // System.out.println("onError");
            }
        });
    }
```

LogCat Error

```
01-07 23:34:36.767 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Thu Jan 07 23:34:36 SGT 2016.jpg: open failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at com.sample.app.ActivityShare.takeScreenshot(ActivityShare.java:225)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at com.sample.app.ActivityShare.access$000(ActivityShare.java:42)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at com.sample.app.ActivityShare$1.onClick(ActivityShare.java:103)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
01-07 23:34:36.787 2024-2024/com.sample.app W/System.err:   ... 16 more
```

i have no idea about the problem.
Please help me. Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the FileName (`mPath`) contains invalid characters - might try removing empty space.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with BlueStack, but perhaps it saves files in a different location than an android device. According to https://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/bluestacks-sd-card-internal-memory-ram.html , the SD location is "C:\Program Data\BlueStacks\Android"

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply! But i Didn't solve the problem yet.